# How to wrap a class from a render method into OnClickOutside via ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, emoji, emojione

I am using EmojiPicker with ReactJS. I have to close EmojiPicker if I click outside of it. How to do it? I am trying to use onClickOutside but I need to wrap EmojiPicker into it and add special method which will change a state of Conversation class (isOpened to false). So firstly I have to add handleClickOutside method to EmojiPicker which will change the state (isOpened) of Conversation to false.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
class Conversation extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            isOpened: false
        }
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                ...OTHER THINGS...

                <EmojiPicker className={this.state.isOpened ? " " : "display-none"} />

                ...OTHER THINGS...
            </div>
        )
}
export default  OnClickOutside(EmojiPicker);
```

Can somebody help me please?

Answer (score 0):

I found this interesting article on providing dynamic super classes to components. It's method could likely be adapted for this use case. 
http://www.mikedoesweb.com/2017/dynamic-super-classes-extends-in-es6/